# CrunchBang - Install option not working

Tags: crunchbang

I've put CrunchBang on my USB device. Live Session is working, but when I choose "Install" it directly returns to the CrunchBang boot options.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the process fails just at the step where it should load the files from the CRDOM.

> Cause description :
>   Actually, at this step, the installer search for the file "/cdrom/dists/wheezy/Release".
>   In the ISO file, th wheezy folder is a link to "/cdrom/dists/sid/Release".
>   When i created my bootable USB stick (the same issue happens whether i used unetbootin or pendrive util), this link disappear and "wheezy" is no longer a link but zero file.
>   I could see the problem by switching to the tty where the installer logs everything (ctrl+alt+f4).

Solution :
As it's on a USB stick, we can write on the mounted disk.
I switched to another tty (ctrl+alt+f2).
What i did was just to remove the "/cdrom/dists/wheezy" zero file.
And i made a "cp -R /cdrom/dists/sid /cdrom/dists/wheezy".
Then i switched back to the graphical installer (ctrl+alt+f5) and continued the installation and everything went smoothly

Originally posted by LittleBigFox.
[Link to #! Official Forum](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=19316)

Worked for me, now I'm writing from my Waldorf.